# Ball rebounds from wicketkeeper's pads or body, can the batsman play it?

Tags: rules, cricket

During the third 2019 Ashes test, a bowled ball (Lyon) passed the batsman (Stokes) without being struck. The ball then hit the wicketkeeper’s (Paine) pad and rolled back more or less in front of the batsman.

The ball was treated as dead if I recall. How do the laws cover this?  Could the ball have been played by the batsman?

Answer (score 1):

No, The batsmen can’t play the ball once it touched any players from the fielding side.
Once it made contact with the wicket keepers pads it is called as a dead ball and is no longer in play.

you can refer to the rule

> 34.2 Not out Hit the ball twice
>
> The striker will not be out under this Law if he/she
>
> 34.2.1 strikes the ball a second or subsequent time in order to return the ball to any fielder.  Note, however, the provisions of Law 37.4 (Returning the ball to a fielder).
>
> **34.2.2 wilfully strikes the ball after it has touched a fielder.  Note, however the provisions of Law 37.1 (Out Obstructing the field).**

Here it can mean that he misses the  ball and hits the keeper or hits the ball and the ball bounces of the nearby fielder.

And LAW 37.4 states

> 37.4 Returning the ball to a fielder
>
> Either batsman is out Obstructing the field if, at any time while the ball is in play and, without the consent of a fielder, he/she uses the bat or any part of his/her person to return the ball to any fielder.

Comment: The ball does not become dead because its touched the wicket keepers pads.  The sole part of the law that is relevant is 34.2.1 and 34.2.2.  It is not dead as the ball could strike the keeper and run away for 4 byes.

Comment: @BenWhyall yeah I’ll edit that out. Thanks